# php dropdown population

Tags: php, mysql

Can some one tell me why the following doesn't populate the dropdown with the the values from the `dist_itnry` column of my database?

```
<?php 
$distUsr = $_SESSION['Distributor_user'];
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL1="SELECT dist_itnry, route FROM sr_itinerary";
$run1=mysql_query($SQL1,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor1=mysql_num_rows($run1);

while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
{
    while ($rec = $distUsr)
    {
        echo "<option id='options'>$rec<br></option>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That inner while loop looks suspicious - if `$distUsr` would cast to boolean true, you'll have an infinite loop there. Also, `$rec` is your row result array, and then you reassign it (in the inner loop) immediately - why? You should do some debugging here - try printing out the number of rows to see if that is correct.

Comment: why are you doing the query when you overwrite `$rec` with `$distUsr`?

Comment: `while ($rec = $distUsr)` doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Also you say in your question *"in the dist_itnry column"*, but you never seem to access that column in your `$rec`.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it should be pointed out that there's no good reason to have a `<br>` within an `<option>`.

Comment: To start with, delete your inner loop, and swap `$rec` with `{$rec['route']}` - if that indeed is the column you want. Drop the `id='options'` as that will produce invalid HTML (`id` attributes must be unique in a document).

Comment: @halfer Thanks.. sure will keep in mind those wht u've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwriting `$rec`. Also, please take a look at the other changes I made like including the `<select>` tag and a more proper usage of the `<option>` tag. You can specify a different value for the `<option>` tag. Example: `<option value="123">Something</option>` - this means "123" will be the value submitted when the form is submitted. But "Something" will be displayed in the form.

The corrected code is listed below:

```
<?php 
$distUsr = $_SESSION['Distributor_user'];
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL1="SELECT dist_itnry, route FROM sr_itinerary";
$run1=mysql_query($SQL1,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor1=mysql_num_rows($run1);
echo '<select name="dropdown">';
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run1))
{
    $value = $rec['dist_itnry'];
    echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```